# How can I change the transparency of a corrplot in R?

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am working in R and I am using the library `corrplot`.

I would like to change the transparency of the `corrplot`, something similar to controlling the `alpha` parameter in `ggplot`.

An example of the code I am using is:

```
x <- rnorm(100,0,1)
y <- rnorm(100,0,1)
z <- rnorm(100,0,1)
cor0 <- cor(cbind(x,y,z))
corrplot::corrplot(cor0, "square")
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to set the colors yourself and their transparency using `scales::alpha`:

```
library(scales)

colors <- scales::alpha(colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))(10), alpha = 0.3)

corrplot::corrplot(cor0, "square", col = colors)
```

[image]